# Injecting Jquery get response using .html() exceeds div limit

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I am using an ajax call to a servlet in order to dynamically get XML configuration and show it to the user. 
Using the promise, I'm injecting the response as html to the container div :

```
        $.ajax({
        url:'XMLServlet',
        type: "get", //send it through get method
          data:{"XSLType":"DB"},
          success: function(response) {
            $('#fullGraphXML').text('<xmp>' +response+'</xmp>');
          },
    })
```

The problem is that the XML exceeds the container div and I cant get it to fit inside using any word-wrap \ width properties to the container div.
If I'm using .text() instead of .html(), it fits good but looks horrible, so I prefer to stick with the .html() function. 
I tried putting it in a  and it didnt help either.
Any suggestios ?

[image]

Comment: can u share a working example on fiddle to check the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the css property `overlow:scroll;` on your `#fullGraphXML`